# How to add superscript text using Apache POI

Tags: apache-poi

I want to display some text with superscript into Excel cell. I tried to pass the HTML string to XSSFRichTextString but it displays the HTML string as it is in the output file.

I'm using Apache POI 3.16

[Screenshot to explain the requirement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GX28X.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are thinking, [RichTextString](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/RichTextString.html) should be able to interpret HTML? It is not. It is only able to [apply Font](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/RichTextString.html#applyFont(int,%20int,%20short)) from `startIndex` to `endIndex`. And [Font](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Font.html) can be marked using [TypeOffset](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Font.html#setTypeOffset(short)) [SS_SUPER](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Font.html#SS_SUPER).

Example:

```
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;

class RichTextSuperscript {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
  Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Sheet1");

  Font fontRed = wb.createFont();
  fontRed.setColor(Font.COLOR_RED);

  Font fontRedSuperscript = wb.createFont();
  fontRedSuperscript.setColor(Font.COLOR_RED);
  fontRedSuperscript.setTypeOffset(Font.SS_SUPER);

  String string = "Level 3";

  RichTextString richString = new XSSFRichTextString( "Level 13" );
                                                     //^0     ^7
  richString.applyFont(7, 8, fontRedSuperscript);

  for (int r = 0; r < 10; r++) {
   Row row = sheet.createRow(r);
   Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
   if ((r%2) == 0) {
    cell.setCellValue(string);
   } else {
    CellUtil.setFont(cell, fontRed);
    cell.setCellValue(richString);
   }
  }

  try {
   wb.write(new FileOutputStream("RichTextSuperscript.xlsx"));
   wb.close();
   } catch (Exception ex) {
   ex.printStackTrace();
  } 
 }
}
```